# Entity Framework with stored procedure using defining query

Tags: entity-framework

I wrote a defining query

```
 <EntitySet Name="EntityFramework" EntityType="SEOAnalysisModel.Store.EntityFramework">
     <DefiningQuery>
         SELECT Keyword, ResultHead ,Year from SeoAnalysis where Year = 2005
     </DefiningQuery>
 </EntitySet>
```

And entity type for custom entity

```
 <EntityType Name="EntityFramework">
     <Key>
         <PropertyRef Name="Year" />
     </Key>
     <Property Name="Year" Nullable="false" Type="int" />
     <Property Name="Keyword" Nullable="false" MaxLength="1000" Type="varchar" />
     <Property Name="ResultHead" Nullable="false" MaxLength="2000" Type="varchar" />
 </EntityType>
```

But when I call a stored procedure, it returns only 1 value of the column

```
// Stored procedure
public void SelectValue() {
    using (MyConnection ctx = new MyConnection()) {
        foreach (var p in ctx.EntityFramework(2005)) {
            Response.Write(p.Keyword);
        }
    }
}
```

And this column value is repetitive.

Now how can I get all column value?

Actually I am getting same keyword repetitive.

If I have keyword like Apple, then this keyword is repeating until loop is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have marked Year as key for the entity. Key must be unique among all records in your defining query otherwise it is not a key. If the key is not unique, EF will do exactly what you got - it will materialize only the first record into entity and use it for all other records as well. EF uses key to identify the entity - if you get two records with the same key value, EF believes that it is the same entity!